# How do you create a VM in Openshift from a qemu-kvm img file and a custom kernel?

Tags: openshift, qemu

We are currently using a qemu kvm, on physical systems, for our testing and would like to move this into our OpenShift cluster.

We are running something like this (other parameters removed for clarity)

`qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel bzImage -drive file=container.ext4.img,format=raw`

When looking at the OpenShift Create VM Wizard I can set source=URL and point to the .img file but see know where to specify the kernel file we use.  When we run just the image file the console says

`Booting from Hard Drive > Boot failed: not a bootable drive`

Is it possible to create a VM in OpenShift using a qemu kvm image and kernel file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is not supported by RH OpenShift