# QEMU - Is it possible to merge a kernel image and drive image into a single raw or qcow2 image?

Tags: openshift, qemu

We are currently using a qemu kvm, on physical systems, that contains a custom kernel and our drive image that we us for our testing and would like to move this to run within our OpenShift cluster.

I have seen where you can use raw or qcow2 images within OpenShift but I have need seen a way to use/specify a custom kernel.

We are running something like this (other parameters removed for clarity)

**qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel bzImage -drive file=container.ext4.img,format=raw**

When looking at the OpenShift Create VM Wizard I can set source=URL and point to the .img file but see know where to specify the kernel file we use. When we run just the image file the console says

Booting from Hard Drive > Boot failed: not a bootable drive

Wondering, is it possible to combine the kernel and drive image into a single file that can use used by OpenShift?

Is there a way in OpenShift to create a VM using a qemu kvm image and a custom kernel file?

Comment: You appear to have asked something very similar before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63581412/how-do-you-create-a-vm-in-openshift-from-a-qemu-kvm-img-file-and-a-custom-kernel

Comment: I think you need to make whatever your image is into a bootable hard disk image. But we don't know what your image actually contains (the root filesystem maybe?).

Comment: Take a live CD, make a suitably large empty disk using qemu-img, boot the live cd with the empty disk and your image attached in a qemu-system VM. Partition disk, copy stuff from your image over, make the thing bootable using grub. And that should be it. You can then try it out, the new file should boot when running just `kvm -hda new.img`